# "A GitHub project url is required" during integration jenkins and github

Tags: jenkins, github, continuous-integration

I'm trying to integrate Jenkins with GitHub by GitHub Pull Request Builder with web hooks. There are job configuration:

Build trigger settings
[image: Build trigger]

Scm settings
[image: Scm]

General settings
[image: General]

After someone push commit I have the exception in Jenkins log:

```
WARNING: org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbTrigger.run() failed for hudson.model.FreeStyleProject@70d6b2ea[CI-pull Request]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A GitHub project url is required.
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbTrigger.initState(GhprbTrigger.java:253)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbTrigger.getRepository(GhprbTrigger.java:708)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbTrigger.isActive(GhprbTrigger.java:697)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbTrigger.run(GhprbTrigger.java:365)
    at hudson.triggers.Trigger.checkTriggers(Trigger.java:278)
    at hudson.triggers.Trigger$Cron.doRun(Trigger.java:226)
    at hudson.triggers.SafeTimerTask.run(SafeTimerTask.java:72)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingScheduledExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingScheduledExecutorService.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your project configuration and make sure you specify the Project url under the "General" section. Very easy to miss. This should be the web url of the project on Github, not the checkout URL.

[image: githubconfiguration]

Comment: Hello, thx for answer! Yes, I put url in this field, but it always add '/' to the end of url, can it broke job?

Comment: I believe it can. There is an issue about it out there.
https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin/issues/539

Comment: What version of the Git and GHPRB are you using? Make sure to be on the latest